# How to create an animated drawing effect on canvas using html5?

Tags: html, canvas, drawing, stroke

i would like to know how to create an nice stroke which blow up some fireworks and nice effects on the stroke line while people are drawing, is that possible? just like this particles appear here in this video [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=gZZaL01zQPc#t=255s)

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet?  What's your experience with canvases, HTML, HTML5, Javascript, etc?

Comment: i know what could be possible i have saw many many examples but none as interesting as the particle video i post... is there anyway to do similar with that? colorful with glow and smoth?????

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you take alook at this, its a pretty good introduction. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/

Answer (score 0):

here: [canvas: create a game-like exploding stars effect for gamification purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670654/canvas-create-a-game-like-exploding-stars-effect-for-gamification-purposes)

Just change the click event to mousemove, as someone even commented.

Comment: That was too simple.. but a good begining.. i would like things more colorful like the video.. but i think i can play with some values there and get some interesting results... thank you anyway :)